# What products can I use to hang herbs under a fluorescent light?

Tags: indoors, containers, light

I have a window-like opening between my kitchen sink and the adjacent room.  On the ceiling of the opening is a fluorescent light, and ideally I'd like to set up a long rectangular hanging basket underneath.  I would also like ideally to use an adjustable chain so that I can keep the plants at a constant distance from the light as they grow.

I'm wondering what options might be available.  I found some correctly shaped baskets online, but can't seem to figure out what to search for regarding adjustable hanging hardware.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind: the weight of the basket and the convenience of raising/lowering.

If I was going to set up something like this, I'd probably screw two sturdy hooks into the ceiling on either side of the light. I'd really want them to sink into studs -- something with a long screw is important.

I'd get a single rectangular basket, roughly the dimensions of the light. If the light isn't hitting the plants directly, they won't grow nearly as well. If you're starting from seed, you'll want the lamp 1/2 to 1" above the soil surface. (This may not be practical if you need that light to do dishes while the seeds are germinating...) Then as the plants are growing you'll want the lamp nearly touching the leaves. If you put the light source too far away from the plants you'll get spindly, leggy, weak plants.

Get some chain from the local hardware store -- small enough that it isn't bulky and ugly, but heavy/sturdy enough to hold the weight of the basket. Oh, and make sure the chain will fit onto the hooks. I'd use four lengths of chain -- two from each hook to each corner of the basket.

It looks like there are two tubes in that light fixture. You can buy full spectrum "grow lights", but I've heard that you can get nearly as effective results by buying one "cool" and one "hot" bulb.